# How to calculate running sum based on conditions in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have the data as below.

| stock | datetime | AVG_Price | MF | NetMF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:15:00 | 234.50 | 237864 | 237864 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:16:00 | 236.55 | 357784 | 595648 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:17:00 | 233.23 | 334959 | 260689 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:18:00 | 233.23 | 498756 | 759445 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:19:00 | 225.23 | 456789 | 302656 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:20:00 | 222.23 | 678546 | -375890 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:21:00 | 222.23 | 567483 | -943373 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-06 09:22:00 | 220.23 | 67483 | -1010856 |

The desired output in NetMF

I want to calculate Net MF using below conditions.

1. At datetime 9:15, I will return MF value into Net MF
2. From 9:16 onwards below is the logic i want to follow

   - If AVG_Price at 9:16 > AVG_Price at 9:15 then Net MF at 9:16 = Net MF at 9:15 + MF at 9:16
   - If AVG_Price at 9:16 < AVG_Price at 9:15 then Net MF at 9:16 = Net MF at 9:15 - MF at 9:16
   - If AVG_Price at 9:16 = AVG_Price at 9:15 and Net MF at 9:15 < 0 then Net MF at 9:16 = Net MF at 9:15 - MF at 9:16
   - If AVG_Price at 9:16 = AVG_Price at 9:15 and Net MF at 9:15 >= 0 then Net MF at 9:16 = Net MF at 9:15 + MF at 9:16

This logic continues till the end of the time period.

I need this logic to work for Multiple stock codes and multiple datetimes.

Currently I have below code in place. This code returns only values for first 1 or 2 rows

```
WITH v_table_name AS
    (
        SELECT stock_code,[datetime], [AVG_Price],[MF], CASE WHEN cast(datetime as time) = '09:15:00.000' and close_price >= open_price THEN [MF] 
                       WHEN cast(datetime as time) = '09:15:00.000' and close_price < open_price THEN -1*[MF] 
                       WHEN Avg_Price > LAG(Avg_Price,1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc) THEN (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) + [MF]
                       WHEN Avg_Price < LAG(Avg_Price,1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc) THEN (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) - [MF]
                       WHEN Avg_Price = LAG(Avg_Price,1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc) and (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) < 0 THEN (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) - [MF]
                       WHEN Avg_Price = LAG(Avg_Price,1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc) and (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) > 0 THEN (LAG([Net MF],1,-1) over (Partition by stock_code order by datetime asc)) + [MF]
                       END as [Net MF] from Equity
    ) 
    UPDATE [Equity] set Equity.[Net MF] = v_table_name.[Net MF]
    FROM v_table_name
    WHERE Equity.stock_code = v_table_name.stock_code
    and Equity.datetime = v_table_name.datetime
```

Comment: please do not use image. Post the sample data as text and also include the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel, Sorry I have updated the question with right format. Thank you

Comment: In your query you have reference to `close_price` and `open_price`. Please include in the sample and also explain the necessary logic

Comment: @Squirrel , AVG_Price is calculated based on open_price & close_price. Hence I have not included them in the data. Also MF is calculated based on volume & AVG_Price. Hence not included Volume in the data

Answer (score 0):

As the `Net MF` depends on previous row value, one simple solution is to use a recursive CTE and calculate the `Net MF` in the recursive part of the `CTE` based on your required condition

```
with 
cte as
(
    select rn = row_number() over (partition by stock_code order by [datetime]),
           stock_code, [datetime], AVG_Price, [MF]
    from   Equity
),
rcte as
(
    -- anchor
    select c.rn, c.stock_code, c.[datetime], c.AVG_Price, c.[MF], [Net MF] = c.[MF]
    from   cte c
    where  c.rn = 1

    union all

    -- recursive
    select c.rn, c.stock_code, c.[datetime], c.AVG_Price, c.[MF],
           [Net MF] = case when c.AVG_Price > r.AVG_Price
                           then r.[Net MF] + c.[MF]
                           when c.AVG_Price < r.AVG_Price
                           then r.[Net MF] - c.[MF]
                           when c.AVG_Price = r.AVG_Price
                           and  r.[Net MF] < 0
                           then r.[Net MF] - c.[MF]
                           when c.AVG_Price = r.AVG_Price
                           and  r.[Net MF] >= 0
                           then r.[Net MF] + c.[MF]  
                           end
    from   cte c
           inner join rcte r on  c.stock_code = r.stock_code
                             and c.rn         = r.rn + 1
)
update e
set    [Net MF] = r.[Net MF]
from   rcte r
       inner join Equity e on   r.stock_code = e.stock_code
                           and  r.[datetime] = e.[datetime]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Note : `open/close price` logic is not in as it is not clear for me. You may add it in yourself

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SQWvzkKK)

Comment: I tried executing above code. I am getting below error. Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 186
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. I have around 100K lines for multiple stock codes and datetime

Comment: add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the end of query

Comment: It takes lot of time to run. I waited for 3 hours. Query keeps on running. Is there any work around for this. Thanks

Comment: That is performance issue. Recursive Query are not exactly performant. Make sure you have the necessary index. Also please post as a new question as it is considered a separate question